# Keep uploads directory under public while deploying new revisions using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, passenger, carrierwave

I have a Rails app and using Apache2 + Passenger + Capistrano on production server:

```
.
├── current -> releases/20150527234152
|   ├── app
|   ├── db
|   ├── lib
|   ├── ...
|   └── public
|       ├── assets
|       └── uploads
|           ├── 01.jpg
|           ├── 02.jpg
|           ├── 03.jpg
|           └── ...
├── releases
|   ├── 20150527212555
|   ├── 20150527230415
|   └── 20150527234152
├── repo
└── shared
```

I am not tracking the `public/uploads` directory (Where images are being uploaded by users). So whenever I do `cap production deploy`, the current links to the new version which won't have the uploads directory anymore. I am using `carrierwave` gem for image upload.

The only solution I can think of is to have capistrano run a script after deploying that moves the directory from older to latest revision.

Or

Have the `uploads` directory outside of the app. (If so, what's the best/safest location for it?)

I want to know which solution is better, or if there is a better option.

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried reading the [documentation](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/configuration/) it is very thorough. I would suggest looking at linked_dirs and linked_files

Comment: Just tried that and it worked. I did go through documentation but just quickly ran through it. Also I did not think linked_dirs works the way it does. Thanks.

Comment: No problem glad it worked out for you capistrano is one of the best documented gems I have found but also one of the most confusing

Comment: Yea, I agree. The documentation for capistrano is pretty good. The gem itself is confusing for me since it's the first time I am using it.
Also, if you can answer this question by linking the documentation, I can accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are looking for is called `linked_dirs`.

It accepts an `Array` of directories and will create a symlink to the directories specified across each successive deployment works well for directories that should persist even when other code is updated as is your case for uploads.

When you deploy what it does is it runs `deploy:check:linked_dirs` to confirm that the path exists and/or creates it. Then it runs `deploy:symlink:linked_dirs` which creates a symlink to this directory.

You can find it in the [Official Documentation](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/configuration/). The Rake Tasks can be Found [Here](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/deploy.rake)